# Add quoted strings support to Antlr3 grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to implement a grammar for parsing queries. Single query consists of `items` where each item can be either `name` or `name-ref`.

`name` is either `mystring` (only letters, no spaces) or `"my long string"` (letters and spaces, always quoted). `name-ref` is very similar to `name` and the only difference is that it should start with `ref:` (`ref:mystring`, `ref:"my long string"`). Query should contain at least 1 item (`name` or `name-ref`).

Here's what I have:

```
NAME: ('a'..'z')+;
REF_TAG: 'ref:';
SP: ' '+;

name: NAME;
name_ref: REF_TAG name;
item: name | name_ref;
query: item (SP item)*;
```

This grammar demonstrates what I basically need to get and the only feature is that it doesn't support long quoted strings (it works fine for names that doesn't have spaces).

```
SHORT_NAME: ('a'..'z')+;
LONG_NAME: SHORT_NAME (SP SHORT_NAME)*;
REF_TAG: 'ref:';
SP: ' '+;
Q: '"';

short_name: SHORT_NAME;
long_name: LONG_NAME;
name_ref: REF_TAG (short_name | (Q long_name Q));
item: (short_name | (Q long_name Q)) | name_ref;
query: item (SP item)*;
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas what's the problem? Probably, that's important: `my first query` should be treated as 3 `item`s (3 `name`s) and `"my first query"` is 1 `item` (1 `long_name`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer matches greedily: that is why input like `my first query` is being tokenized as `LONG_NAME` instead of 3 `SHORT_NAME`s with spaces in between.

Simply remove the `LONG_NAME` rule and define it in the parser rule `long_name`.

The following grammar:

```
SHORT_NAME : ('a'..'z')+;
REF_TAG    : 'ref:';
SP         : ' '+;
Q          : '"';

short_name : SHORT_NAME;
long_name  : Q SHORT_NAME (SP SHORT_NAME)* Q;
name_ref   : REF_TAG (short_name | (Q long_name Q));
item       : short_name | long_name | name_ref;
query      : item (SP item)*;
```

will parse the input:

```
my first query "my first query" ref:mystring
```

as follows:

[image]

However, you *could* also tokenize a quoted name in the lexer and strip the quotes from it with a bit of custom code. And removing spaces from the lexer could also be an option. Something like this:

```
SHORT_NAME : ('a'..'z')+;
LONG_NAME  : '"' ~'"'* '"' {setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));};
REF_TAG    : 'ref:';
SP         : ' '+ {skip();};

name_ref   : REF_TAG (SHORT_NAME | LONG_NAME);
item       : SHORT_NAME | LONG_NAME | name_ref;
query      : item+ EOF;
```

which would parse the same input as follows:

[image]

Note that the actual token `LONG_NAME` will be stripped of its start- and end-quote.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of `"` under `long_name` node? I want the for syntax, but I don't need them when working with results of parsing. Will really appreciate non-inline-Java solution.

Comment: @loki2302, you mean from the first tree-image? EDIT: wait, I see you accepted my answer. This means you have no question(s) anymore?

Comment: I've just responded before seeing you've updated your answer. Well, yes. Basically my question here is - is there a way to implement your second approach without Java string procedures?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a grammar that should work for your requirements:

```
  SP: ' '+;
  SHORT_NAME: ('a'..'z')+;
  LONG_NAME: '"' SHORT_NAME (SP SHORT_NAME)* '"';
  REF: 'ref:' (SHORT_NAME | LONG_NAME);

  item: SHORT_NAME | LONG_NAME  | REF;
  query: item (SP item)*;
```

If you put this at the top:

```
  grammar Query;

  @members {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          QueryLexer lex = new QueryLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]));
           CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);

          QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(tokens);

          try {
              TokenSource ts = parser.getTokenStream().getTokenSource();
              Token tok = ts.nextToken();
              while (EOF != (tok.getType())) {
                 System.out.println("Got a token: " + tok);
                 tok = ts.nextToken();
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
  }
```

You should see the lexer break everything apart nicely (I hope ;-) )

```
hi there "long name" ref:shortname ref:"long name"
```

Should give:

```
Got a token: [@-1,0:1='hi',<6>,1:0]
Got a token: [@-1,2:2=' ',<7>,1:2]
Got a token: [@-1,3:7='there',<6>,1:3]
Got a token: [@-1,8:8=' ',<7>,1:8]
Got a token: [@-1,9:19='"long name"',<4>,1:9]
Got a token: [@-1,20:20=' ',<7>,1:20]
Got a token: [@-1,21:33='ref:shortname',<5>,1:21]
Got a token: [@-1,34:34=' ',<7>,1:34]
Got a token: [@-1,35:49='ref:"long name"',<5>,1:35]
```

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is with your grammar, but I suspect the issue relates to your definition of a `LONG_NAME` without the quotes. Perhaps you can see what the distinction is?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't eliminate helper characters like quotes and `ref:` tag.